# mongodb not follow prefix rule

Tags: mongodb, indexing

mongodb often use index which include the field no in the filter , and the field will using [MaxKey , MinKey] ,this is not the same as what I saw in the index prefix documentation.

the query like this :

```
db.Wager.aggregate([
    {"$match": 
        {
            "CompanyId": 1341, 
            "UpdatedDateUtc" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2021-03-25T23:35:00Z")}
        }},
    {$project:
        {"CompanyId":1,"UpdatedDateUtc":1,_id:0}
    },
    {"$group": 
        {"_id": 1,"n": {"$sum": 1}}
    }
])
```

I hope this can use this index :

```
{ "CompanyId": -1, "UpdatedDateUtc" : -1 ,"WagerEventDateUtc" : -1 }
```

but it always will use index :

```
{ "CompanyId" : 1,"BetDateUtc" : -1, "WagerEventDateUtc" : -1, "UpdatedDateUtc" : -1}
```

there is the explain :

```
{
    "nReturned": 101,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
    "totalKeysExamined": 101,
    "totalDocsExamined": 0,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "PROJECTION_COVERED",
        "nReturned": 101,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "works": 101,
        "advanced": 101,
        "needTime": 0,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 3,
        "restoreState": 2,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "transformBy": {
            "CompanyId": 1,
            "UpdatedDateUtc": 1,
            "_id": 0
        },
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 101,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "works": 101,
            "advanced": 101,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 3,
            "restoreState": 2,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "keyPattern": {
                "CompanyId": 1,
                "BetDateUtc": -1,
                "WagerEventDateUtc": -1,
                "UpdatedDateUtc": -1
            },
            "indexName": "CompanyId_1_BetDateUtc_-1_WagerEventDateUtc_-1_UpdatedDateUtc_-1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
                "CompanyId": [],
                "BetDateUtc": [],
                "WagerEventDateUtc": [],
                "UpdatedDateUtc": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
                "CompanyId": [
                    "[1341.0, 1341.0]"
                ],
                "BetDateUtc": [
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ],
                "WagerEventDateUtc": [
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ],
                "UpdatedDateUtc": [
                    "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1616715300000)]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined": 101,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0
        }
    }
},
{
    "nReturned": 101,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
    "totalKeysExamined": 101,
    "totalDocsExamined": 0,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "PROJECTION_COVERED",
        "nReturned": 101,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "works": 101,
        "advanced": 101,
        "needTime": 0,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 10242,
        "restoreState": 10242,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "transformBy": {
            "CompanyId": 1,
            "UpdatedDateUtc": 1,
            "_id": 0
        },
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 101,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
            "works": 101,
            "advanced": 101,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 10242,
            "restoreState": 10242,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "keyPattern": {
                "CompanyId": -1,
                "UpdatedDateUtc": -1,
                "WagerEventDateUtc": -1
            },
            "indexName": "CompanyId_-1_UpdatedDateUtc_-1_WagerEventDateUtc_-1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
                "CompanyId": [],
                "UpdatedDateUtc": [],
                "WagerEventDateUtc": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
                "CompanyId": [
                    "[1341.0, 1341.0]"
                ],
                "UpdatedDateUtc": [
                    "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1616715300000)]"
                ],
                "WagerEventDateUtc": [
                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined": 101,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0
        }
    }
}
```

I think mongodb choose wrong index were because "saveState" and "restoreState" too high , but I'm not sure because I don’t know what these two fields mean.

Comment: I was wondering what is your real issue with this. If you nevertheless need both indexes then let just mongodb choose whatever index it wants to use. It is already perfectly optimized since the ratio between examined key and returned docs is 1. If you dont want it to use that index, try to delete it and run an explain again.

Comment: Hi @SebastianK , my question is my query filter haven't BetDateUtc and WagerEventDateUtc , why mongodb choose { "CompanyId" : 1,"BetDateUtc" : -1, "WagerEventDateUtc" : -1, "UpdatedDateUtc" : -1} ; it was different with mongodb prefix doc said ( https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/index-compound/#prefixes )

Comment: That is indeed a good question. I can't answer that without having a look at an example collection. One addition: you can use hint(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) to force mongo db to use a specific index.

Comment: Hi @SebastianK , there is the sample doc :
{"_id" : ObjectId("00000000000000000000000"),"CompanyId" : 0000,"WagerId" : NumberLong(000000000),"BetDateUtc" : ISODate("2021-02-04T05:59:52.405Z"),"UpdatedDateUtc" : ISODate("2021-02-04T06:03:27.551Z"),"SettledDateUtc" : ISODate("2021-02-04T06:03:27.551Z"),"WagerEventDateUtc" : ISODate("2021-02-04T06:01:03Z")}

Answer (score 0):

The answer to why is chooses one index over another is it runs a short test, calculates which index returns the most results per unit of "work", with bonus points for completing during the test or not using a blocking sort.

If 2 or more indexes are tied after that, it randomly picks one.